# Link to PDF from menu

Tags: xslt, umbraco

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE xsl:stylesheet [ <!ENTITY nbsp "&#x00A0;"> ]>
<xsl:stylesheet
  version="1.0"
  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
  xmlns:msxml="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt"
  xmlns:umbraco.library="urn:umbraco.library" xmlns:Exslt.ExsltCommon="urn:Exslt.ExsltCommon" xmlns:Exslt.ExsltDatesAndTimes="urn:Exslt.ExsltDatesAndTimes" xmlns:Exslt.ExsltMath="urn:Exslt.ExsltMath" xmlns:Exslt.ExsltRegularExpressions="urn:Exslt.ExsltRegularExpressions" xmlns:Exslt.ExsltStrings="urn:Exslt.ExsltStrings" xmlns:Exslt.ExsltSets="urn:Exslt.ExsltSets"
  exclude-result-prefixes="msxml umbraco.library Exslt.ExsltCommon Exslt.ExsltDatesAndTimes Exslt.ExsltMath Exslt.ExsltRegularExpressions Exslt.ExsltStrings Exslt.ExsltSets ">

<xsl:output method="xml" omit-xml-declaration="yes" />

<xsl:param name="currentPage"/>
<xsl:variable name="MediaNodeId" select="./@id"/>
<!-- Input the documenttype you want here -->
<xsl:variable name="level" select="1"/>

<xsl:template match="/">

<!-- The fun starts here -->
<ul class=" menu nav">
<xsl:for-each select="$currentPage/ancestor-or-self::* [@level=$level]/* [@isDoc and string(umbracoNaviHide) != '1']">
  <li>
    <a href="{umbraco.library:NiceUrl(@id)}">
      <xsl:value-of select="@nodeName"/>
    </a>
    <xsl:if test="count(./child::*[@isDoc and string(umbracoNaviHide) != '1']) &gt; 0">
      <ul>
        <xsl:for-each select="./child::*[@isDoc and string(umbracoNaviHide) != '1']">
          <li>
            <xsl:choose>

                <xsl:when test="name()= 'Link' ">

                <xsl:if test="linkUrl!=''">
                   <a href="{umbraco.library:GetMedia(linkUrl, 0)/umbracoFile}" target="_blank">
                     <xsl:value-of select="@nodeName"/></a>
              </xsl:if>
                </xsl:when>         

               <xsl:otherwise>
                <a href="{umbraco.library:NiceUrl(@id)}">
                <xsl:value-of select="@nodeName"/></a>
              </xsl:otherwise>

           </xsl:choose>   

             <xsl:if test="count(./child::*[@isDoc and string(umbracoNaviHide) != '2']) &gt; 0">
      <ul>
        <xsl:for-each select="./child::*[@isDoc and string(umbracoNaviHide) != '2']">
          <li>
            <a href="{umbraco.library:NiceUrl(@id)}">
              <xsl:value-of select="@nodeName"/>
            </a>
          </li>
        </xsl:for-each>
      </ul>  
    </xsl:if>
          </li>
        </xsl:for-each>
      </ul>  
    </xsl:if>
  </li>
</xsl:for-each>
</ul>
<div id="jflanguageselection"><div class="rawimages"><span id="active_language"><a href="http://www.hooymans-duivensport.nl/nl"><img src="/images/nl.gif" alt="Nederlands (NL-nl)" title="Nederlands (NL-nl)" /></a></span><span><a href="http://www.hooymans-duivensport.nl/en"><img src="/images/en.gif" alt="English (United Kingdom)" title="English (United Kingdom)" /></a></span></div></div>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

I need to make a link in the menu on the pdf file I get this error.

Error occured

System.OverflowException: Value was either too large or too small for an Int32.
at System.Convert.ToInt32(Double value)
at System.Convert.ChangeType(Object value, Type conversionType, IFormatProvider provider)
at System.Xml.Xsl.Runtime.XmlQueryRuntime.ChangeTypeXsltArgument(XmlQueryType xmlType, Object value, Type destinationType)
at System.Xml.Xsl.Runtime.XmlQueryContext.InvokeXsltLateBoundFunction(String name, String namespaceUri, IList`1[] args)
at (XmlQueryRuntime {urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt-debug}runtime)
at Root(XmlQueryRuntime {urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt-debug}runtime)
at System.Xml.Xsl.XmlILCommand.Execute(Object defaultDocument, XmlResolver dataSources, XsltArgumentList argumentList, XmlWriter writer)
at System.Xml.Xsl.XslCompiledTransform.Transform(IXPathNavigable input, XsltArgumentList arguments, TextWriter results)
at umbraco.presentation.webservices.codeEditorSave.SaveXslt(String fileName, String oldName, String fileContents, Boolean ignoreDebugging)

Comment: Do you know the exact line/block that is throwing the error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error is common in Umbraco upon XSLT parsing as the parser assumes that some of your data may be null/empty, when in reality it may be [always] assigned.

The trick is find the culprit line of code and enclose it a test-for-empty-if-block.

For example, it may or may not be this line, although it quite commonly occurs with `@id` and `NiceUrl()`:

```
<xsl:otherwise>
    <xsl:if test="@id != ''">
        <a href="{umbraco.library:NiceUrl(@id)}">
            <xsl:value-of select="@nodeName"/>
        </a>
    </xsl:if>
</xsl:otherwise>
```

The error is likely to arise from the `GetMedia()`<sup>1</sup> or `NiceUrl()`<sup>2</sup> calls as they require a parameter of type Int32 to be passed, but I can see you've already enclosed your `GetMedia()` call in an if-block.

<sup>1</sup> http://our.umbraco.org/forum/developers/xslt/30131-Loading-Xslt-Value-was-either-too-large-or-too-small-for-an-Int32-

<sup>2</sup> http://our.umbraco.org/forum/developers/xslt/3102-Using-niceurl-Value-was-either-too-large-or-too-small-for-an-Int32-

Comment: In the case where you are looping through page nodes @id is never empty because all INode objects must have an id attribute.

Comment: @Digbyswift - Did you even read my answer? You do realise that I used that line of code as an _example_ to prove another point? That sometimes you need to enclose the erroring line inside an IF block to get it working. I even said it may not be this specific line of code. You're right in that all _page_ nodes must contain an ID attribute, but the parser doesn't assume this, it makes assumptions based on the _actual_ XML where not all _actual_ nodes have an ID (Umbraco properties, for instance). Try to execute the XSLT at this [PasteBin](http://pastebin.com/Tyw0Zust) to see exactly what I mean.

Comment: Yes I did, and you should be clearer in your answer. By using the @id and NiceUrl() as examples in an Umbraco-tagged post you are creating confusion for subsequent users.

Comment: @Digbyswift - 95% of the time we encounter this error, it's directly a result of `@id` and `NiceUrl()`, no matter the context. Here's another [Post](http://our.umbraco.org/forum/developers/xslt/3102-Using-niceurl-Value-was-either-too-large-or-too-small-for-an-Int32-) illustrating it's frequency. It's possible that the error could come from the `GetMedia()` call, but that's already enclosed in an if-block, so my suspicions immediately fall onto the `NiceUrl()` calls. Until the asker specifies which line is causing the error, I can only use examples.

Comment: Well they say persistence pays :) Can you edit your answer to include a link to the post to support your answer?

Comment: @Digbyswift - Indeed :) essentially we're after the same thing - An answer that's helpful/clear to all subsequent users as well as the original asker. Apologies if it wasn't clear first time round.